Can't bake texture from one uv map to another
What I want to do: I made a fabric texture for a table cloth and Im trying to bake it into another uv map so that I can add details to only the edges of the texture and upload it to sketchFab with pbr materials.
What my scene looks like: My entire material is plugged into a uv map node "pattern" and my target image for baking is plugged into a uv map node "bake map". I haven't changed the bake settings and in object data for my fabric I have the "bake map" selected for render.
The issue: When i press bake the result it rendered on the "pattern" uv map
